# Making HTTP POST call in Java with file

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to make a HTTP POST call to upload a file (and also has to fill parameters ex. title) to restful web service:

This is what I tried to do:

```
    File file = new File(filepath);

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); //DefaultHTTPClient is deprecated?
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    //Multipart Entity is also deprecated?? 
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart("file[path]", new FileBody(file));
    post.setEntity((HttpEntity) entity);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is not working. I am not sure how to upload the file and add the parameters and make the call? I tried this using [Java Http Client to upload file over POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6917105/java-http-client-to-upload-file-over-post/6917303#6917303) but the ones he/she used is deprecated? I have httpcore 4.4 alpha jar

Answer (score 0):

Yes the classes you use are deprecated. Try this example:

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/examples/org/apache/http/examples/entity/mime/ClientMultipartFormPost.java

Comment: I have a question MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                    .addPart("bin", bin)
                    .addPart("comment", comment)
                    .build(); What are these parts thats being added? Is that the parameters?

Comment: To which restfull service are you trying to upload to?

Comment: A custom one given to me. It has the ability to accept files and the service part works